# error: expected unqualified-id before 'not' token g c++ builder

Tags: c++, cygwin

I have a class Notification in program and I use it in other class in this project. It ok when I run in Visual studio 2010. But when use Cygwin build occcur this error:

> error: expected unqualified-id before 'not' token"

This my code:

```
std::vector<int> *not = new std::vector<int>();
not->push_back(100);
delete not;
```

Answer (score 8):

`not` is a keyword in C++ (an alias for `!`). Rename your variable to something else.

Comment: +1.  Presumably to avoid breaking old code, Visual Studio tends to ignore this part of the Standard unless you explicitly enable it on the compiler command line, which of course just encourages writing broken/non-portable new code in VS now.

Answer (score 2):

`not` is a C++ keyword, alias for the `!` operator.

Microsoft Visual C++ is well known for not following the specification whenever Microsoft didn't feel like it. Which was whenever their existing code base didn't conform, they didn't like the specification, they had a bug and didn't feel like fixing it or any other reason. Don't rely on MSVC++ for checking any code that is supposed to be portable.